# speed-up to heap memory access in C++

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

Due to a simulation propose, I need to model a small memory system consist of cells, blocks and pages. this way, I implemented this memory as follow:

```
typedef struct block {
    double lifetime[320];
    block * next;
} block;
```

And I send billions of write to each page like this:

```
vector<vector<block>>  MainMem(max_page, vector<block>(num_blocks_per_page));
for(double  cWrite = 0 ;  MainMem.size()  ; ++cWrite)
    for(int page_index = 0 ; page_index < MainMem.size() ; page_index ++)
          for(int block_index = 0 ; block_index < max_blocks; block_index++)
                for(int cell = 0 ; cell < max_cell; cell++){
                    MainMem[page_index][cnt_block].lifetime[cell] --;
```

Unfortunately, this is a very time-consuming process. I tried stack-based instead of heap-based but because of small capacity of stack that was not satisfying for me.

Comment: `for(double  cWrite = 0 ;  MainMem.size()  ; ++cWrite)` Is this really your actual loop? The condition of the loop seems to be wrong.

Comment: Saying `typedef struct X { } X;` is unnecessary in C++, just say `struct X { };`

Comment: The most outer loop is an infinite one...

Comment: @JBL Which is great, because it leaves ample room for optimization!

Comment: @sehe, I suppose that's true, but even a 99% speedup wouldn't mean much.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen Although, the sun is expected to burn out in 4.5 to 5 billion years. 99% of that is ~5 billion years saved!

Answer (score 0):

It will be impossible to quantify any possible speedup without measuring, but here is something that could help in theory. You will have to implement and test it.

When you use a `vector<vector<block>>`, you need one allocation for the outer `vector` plus one allocation for every inner `vector`. In addition to that, you have an extra level of indirection, possibly resulting in (more) cache misses. Especially the second part can be quite significant.

To avoid this, use a simple `vector<block>`. You will either have to change your indexing from `MainMem[i][j]` to `MainMem[i*num_blocks_per_page + j]` or wrap it in a class with an `operator[]` that does that logic for you. It is possibly important to inline its implementation.

(I guess that your loops are not broken in your real code.)